# Fresnel Integrals by by Contour Integration, Don't Understand Step

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So I'm following the proof in Stefan's answer [How to do Fresnel Integration using Complex Analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908772/how-to-do-fresnel-integration-using-complex-analysis). I don't understand how he goes from $\int_{0}^{R} e^{-(re^{i\ \frac{\pi}{4}})^2} e^{({i \frac{\pi}{4}})} dr$ to $(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}) \int_{0}^{R} e^{-ir^2} dr$.

Actually, I'm really confused as to how the evaluate at all the part of the first integral that is $e^(e{^{2i\frac{\pi}{4}}})$. Could somehow help me see what you're supposed to do here?

Comment: Euler's Formula $e^{ix}=cos(x)+i\cdot sin(x)$ is what you need to apply.  For $x=\pi/4$ and $x=\pi /2$ you should find that the sin/cos terms evaluate out to much simpler constants.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter Thank you! Got it